# Stepper Motor is moving when I put hand near cables?

Tags: stepper-motor, wiring

I wired my RaspberryPi Zero 2 with stepper motor. It works fine, just when the motor is stopped and I put my hand near cables (especially MS1, MS2, MS3) (without touching anything) motor starts to vibrate and move. What could cause this?

Comment: bad wiring ... bad program ... what's MS1, etc?

Comment: Got it, I don't know why, but when I changed one most suspicious cable it stopped. Something like magnetic field?

Comment: It sounds like Electromagnetic interference (EMI), because of the static your body is producing, it can appear if the switching frequency is high and voltage is low. Have you tried using a shielded cable (you will have to ground the cable shield)?